# Using the UpdateCursor on a shapefile to update a Field "SIZE" to assign as large (100000) or small (less than 100000) base on population

Tags: arcpy

```
import arcpy
#set workplace value
arcpy.env.workspace = r"F:\Labs\Working\lab7\lecture08data"
fields = ['SIZE']

fc = "airports.shp" 
#Set update cursor that lays based on the size of the airport.
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,"SIZE",'"SIZE"<100000')
for row in cursor:
    #Update name value
    if Status1[0] = 'Large':
       Status2[0]='Small'
    cursor.updateRow(row)

del row
del cursor
```

[image: A image attach to this post shows the attribute table of the shapefile. I would like to update the field "Size"]

---

I made a few updates to the script as highlighted shown in the image to update my shapefile through ArcMap. Everything works perfectly.

Comment: This should have generated a syntax error, since you used the assignment operator (`=`) instead of the equivalence operator (`==`).

Comment: Please actually ask a question in the body of your question

Comment: GIS SE uses a Question/Answer model. Questions are expected to have words (in English) to describe the environment, task, data, attempted solution, and problem details, with exactly one question. When you answer the question in the question, and that answer is the same as the Answer you were provided, it breaks the model (and garners downvotes).  Thanks are not necessary, but clicking the green checkbox for the answer that put you on the road to success is expected. Please see the [Tour] for a description of how things work here.

Answer (score 3):

What's nice about arcpy.da.UpdateCursor and with is you don't need to clean up, Python does it for you when you drop out of the with:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["TOT_ENP", "SIZE"]): as rows:
    for row in rows:
        if row[0] < 100000: 
            row[1] = "Small"
        else: 
            row[1] = "Large"
        rows.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. I'm going to run it.

Comment: "I would like to share that I made a few changes from the previous script due to error that the "name 'rows' is not defined'.                                                                                            
 fc = "airports.shp" 
cursor= arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["TOT_ENP","SIZE"],'"SIZE"=\'\'')
for row in cursor:
    if row[0] < 100000: 
       row[1] = "Small"
    else: 
       row[1] = "Large"
    cursor.updateRow(row)
    
print "DONE"
del row
del cursor